# Call parent prototype from child prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

My parent class is

```
   function Parent() {}

   Parent.prototype.get = function() {}

   Parent.prototype.start= function() {  this._start() }
```

My child is

```
   function Child(){ Parent.call(this, arguments) }

   Child.prototype._start = function(){   this.get() /* error here - this.get is not a function*/ }  

   util.inherits(Child, Parent);
```

When I do

```
    new Child().start()
```

I got an error `this.get is not a function`. How can I call parent prototype function? Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(this)` to see what `this` references

Comment: Consider using ES6 classes and the `super` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the use of `util.inherits` is discouraged, you should use [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) for classes, but you seem to have just regular functions, which means you can set the prototype of the child to the same as the parent before starting to extend it further

```js
function Parent() {}

Parent.prototype.get = function() {
  console.log('works fine');
}

Parent.prototype.start = function() {
  this._start();
}


function Child() {
  Parent.call(this, arguments);
}

Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

Child.prototype._start = function() {
  this.get();
}


var instance = new Child();

instance.start();
```

Note that Parent and Child now have the same prototype, so by changing one, you'd be changing the other as well.
If for some reason you have to avoid that, using `Object.create` *(or assign)* would do that

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```